# Find the differential invariants of $G_1 = \frac{e^{-wt}}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, lie-algebras

I am given an ODE and its symmetries.
I need to find the differential invariants of
$$
G_1 = \frac{e^{-wt}}{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
$$

In order to do this I need to solve the system of equations:

$$
\frac{dt}{\xi} = \frac{dy}{\eta} = \frac{dy'}{\eta^{(1)}}\\
$$

Since $\eta = 0$ my first invariant is $r = y$.

Now in finding the second invariant I have the following:
[image]
\begin{align}
\xi & = \frac{e^{-wt}}{y} \\
\eta^{(1)} &= \frac{we^{-wt}}{y}y' + \frac{e^{-wt}}{y^2}y'^2\\
\end{align}

the given second invariant is:

$v = e^{wt}[1 + w\frac{y}{y_t}]$

Have I determined $\xi, \eta^{(1)}, \eta^{(2)}$ correctly?

Here is what I have done:

\begin{align}
dtye^{wt} &= \frac{y^2e^{wt}dy'}{ywy'+y'^2}\\ 
\frac{1}{y}dt &= \frac{1}{ywy'+y'^2}dy'\\
\frac{1}{y}t &= \frac{-\ln\left(\frac{yw}{y'}+1\right)}{yw} + \ln C \\
wt &= -\ln \left(\frac{yw}{y'}+1\right) + \ln C\\
\ln C = wt + \ln \left(\frac{yw}{y'}+1\right) \\
C = e^{wt}\left(\frac{yw}{y'}+1\right)\\
\end{align}

This gives me the desired second invariant. Is this mathematically correct?